2013 Jaguar XF Shaking When Idling/Accelerating
2013 Jaguar XF Shakes When Idle/Accelerating
Hello,
I was driving back for a two hour drive and my 2013 Jaguar XF began to shake a lot whenever I accelerated and whenever I let the car idle. It did not shake when coasting.
I am concerned and not too experienced with cars and am trying to figure out what I can do before I go to a shop.
Here are the codes I scanned from the OBD2 port:

U0447: Invalid data received from serial data gateway Module ‘A’
P02F3: Cylinder 6 injector circuit range/performance
P2198: O2 sensor signal biased/stuck rich bank 2 sensor 1
P0306: Cylinder 6 misfire detected
P1315: Persistent misfire

I’ve looked up these codes individually and the main suggestion I see is to check, clean, and replace the spark plug if needed but I am a bit concerned with the other issues mentioned like the oxygen sensor…
I would appreciate anyone who can give some advice on this, particularly with codes possibly being related to each other.
Thanks

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

You don't state how many miles are on the vehicle, nor if the O2 sensors have been changed (this depends on mileage). That said, I think the two codes (U0447 & P2198) are unrelated to the real issue. (These two codes are probably previous codes and would most likely go away and not come back if the codes were cleared ... just a hunch on my part.)  Obviously you have a misfire in cylinder 6.  Your 3.0L V6 is supercharged and direct injected. Both of these things are great for performance, however, it makes it a little tougher to diagnose than it would be for a sequential port fuel injected (SPFI) based engine. The problem may either be that there is a problem with the wiring going from the ECU to the injector (less likely) or there's a problem with the injector on cyl #6 (most likely).

Hey Paulster, thanks for making sense of those codes. I cleared them with my reader and the injector one showed up again so I think what you said about it or the electrical system is some good direction.
